# Kendo UI Vue - typings

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-vue

Are there any type definitions for Kendo UI Vue components? Is it possible to use it along with Typescript? In Kendo UI React the type definitions are part of npm packages, but it seems not for Vue.

Comment: At the moment there are no typings for Kendo UI Vue. Yet it is based on the Kendo widgets and there are very few other methods in it so the typings of Kendo widgets can be used.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you mean typings for the jQuery kendo.ui? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/kendo-ui 
I tried that with no luck, there are different namespaces I would say.